# Mobile sign in apps?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, mobile

I need to create a web app that works for both compters and mobile devices. The app will require a login. How I understand it is that if I create just a mobile version of the website then I loose the ability  to have a icon for the phone and the user will have to manually login each time.

To avoid that can I just create simple iPhone/ android apps that's only function is to store login info and provide the user with an icon to easily access the site? Would that be my best approach?

Comment: can you elaborate more on "**the ability to have a icon for the phone **"

Comment: I want the user to have an icon on their phone that they can use to conveniently access the web app. When the user clicks on the phone icon it should take the user right into the web app without requiring the user to input their username and password to the app each time.

Answer (score 0):

For icon thing itself, for IPhone there is a way to achieve this, you have to set link tags in head of your page

## IPhone (and Android according to this [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aFfz4TSa8qqIJ%3awww.mollerus.net/tom/blog/2010/06/web_app_homescreen_icons_in_android.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us))

The first is to use the icon as is, all that is added are rounded corners. To do this we use this link tag:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/icon.png"/>
```

The second option gives the icon the standard Apple gloss:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/icon.png"/>
```

Splash screen image

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash.png" />
```

Make app full screen

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

## Blackbery

... not sure how using html, but if want to make native app for it...
[Check this link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Create_a_web_icon.html?nodeid=1487655&vernum=0)

## One Time sign in

You can use persistent cookies to achieve this. Just set cookie expiration time somewhere in far far future and user will be logged in next time he visits your page.

Comment: Does that work with android? And what about the authentaction issue -will the user still need to login each time?

Comment: Works with android and user will stay loged in, read above answer all is there

Comment: How secure is using persistent cookies though? The site stores billing information so it needs to be secure.

Comment: there is way to secure cookies. Create two cookies, one for http and https and second one only for https. The thing is, your second, secured cookie should be used to verify if cookie which is unsecured is made in pair with this secured one on login. So you can use still unsecured pages (no https) but check if userId in secured cookie match userId in unsecured before you need to show secured content, like billing info. On the other hand, I suggest that you avoid "returning" back to browser billing information, create your token which you will show to customer as alias for billing info....

Comment: Another thing, there is no way to create web app which has login capabilities without doing hard work and reinventing wheel. Cookies are ok if you use it with ssl

Comment: BTW, find some article on internet about PCI compliance. there are few levels which your app need to satisfy in order to minimize costs in case disaster